# How to serve static files in dynamic route with express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a web application which I need to serve save set of files with different paths.

I wrote a website in the folder `./foo/`, which have 3 files, `index.html`, `style.css`, and `main.js`

I would like to serve the website in `./foo/` folder to the following paths.

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/a/
http://localhost:8080/foo/b/
http://localhost:8080/foo/c/
```

So that, the following links would return the corresponding files in `./foo/` folder.

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/a/index.html
http://localhost:8080/foo/a/style.css
http://localhost:8080/foo/a/main.js

http://localhost:8080/foo/b/index.html
http://localhost:8080/foo/b/style.css
http://localhost:8080/foo/b/main.js

http://localhost:8080/foo/c/index.html
http://localhost:8080/foo/c/style.css
http://localhost:8080/foo/c/main.js
```

---

The following code works for me. Express serve the correct files.

```
app.use("/foo/:id/", express.static("./lib/foo/"));
```

However, I do not need the id attribute, so I replace `:id` with `*`

```
app.use("/foo/*/", express.static("./lib/foo/"));
```

The above code doesn't work. Express return contents of `./foo/index.html` and add a trailing slash to the url, no matter which path I request.

For example, when I enter `http://localhost:8080/foo/a/style.css`, the server should return `./foo/style.css`, but instead it inserts trailing slash to the url (`http://localhost:8080/foo/a/style.css/`), and return `index.html`, which is the wrong file to return.

---

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/express-gbnb3

How could I fix my server?

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Please add to your question multiple descriptive examples of what you do and don't want your route to cover.  Apparently, you want it to work for more than just `bar.css`.  What about all other filenames at that level.  What about paths with deeper levels?  What about paths that are missing a filename and just end in a directory name?

Comment: Also, if you don't want `index.html` to be returned except when the path ends with `index.html`, you can specify `{index: false}` in the `express.static()` [options](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static).

Comment: You've described absolutely no reason why you can't just use `app.use("/foo/:id/", express.static("./lib/foo/"));`.  Why change from that?  You said it works.  There's no meaningful cost to using `:id` in the URL, even if your current code doesn't need to use the value of the id right now.

Comment: Wouldn't adding a attribute affect performance of the server?